# Manhattan Name Change Records

Tags: united-states, surnames

My great grandfather immigrated to NYC from Lomza Gubernia of Biyalstok Province of Russian EMpire (Poland today) in 1885.   We don't know his original name, though the family lore is his name was Golembek.  It was a Jewish name in that part of POland. On 2 Dec. 1888 he married under the name Charles Edward Silverman and that is the name for which we have records.

I suspect he changed his name but would love to find the court record if it exists.  Then we can trace his family back to Lomza.   How do we check on name change records for Lower East Side of Manhattan from period 1885-88.

Comment: What documents do you have so far? Was he naturalized? A naturalization record sometimes lists the name under which the person immigrated. Do you know for sure that his name was not some variant of "Charles Edward Silverman"? Does the name "Golembek" appear in any written documents, letters, etc. or is this an aural/oral lore? That is, did you ever see it spelled "Golembek" or is that just what the name sounded like?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take a look at https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/10529/1006 and the question  https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2452/1006 and see if any of the information in the answers there can help. Also, letting us know what records you already have might help.