# Seeking change of name documents for Manhattan in 1890s

Tags: united-states, surnames, new-york-city, 1890s

My Great Grandfather Moritz Stechil, was a widow and married in Manhattan September 13, 1891. However, when my grandfather was born, the last name changed to Steckler. My grandfather’s birth certificate shows Harris STECKLER born July 15, 1906 in Manhattan and my great grandfather’s name was written Morris Steckler.

Would there be a change of name document for this?

Comment: Hi, Rachel, welcome to G&FH.SE! We already have a couple of questions about name changes on the site like this one. https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18126/1006 where you might get some clues about records that might exist.  The answer is "it depends" and changes for the time and place.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I know for a fact he must have changed his name sometime prior to 1903, as I found his name Morris STECKLER as owner of Morris Cigars in NYC in a business directory. My search continues